# Non-degenerate pairing in the context of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I'm trying to do exercise 2.2.3 on Huybrechts, Complex Geometry:

Show that for any holomorphic vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$ there exists a non-degenerate pairing $$\Lambda^k E\times \Lambda^{r-k} E\to \Lambda^r E.$$

I don't understand what is the meaning of pairing in this context, because $\Lambda^k E\times \Lambda^{r-k} E$ is not a bundle.

For vector spaces, it is relatively easy to get a non-degenerate pairing $\Lambda^k V\times \Lambda^{r-k} V\to \Lambda^r V$ via $(v_1\wedge\ldots\wedge v_k, w_1\ldots\wedge w_{r-k})\mapsto (v_1\wedge\ldots\wedge w_{r-k})$ but I don't know how to translate this to the vector bundles.

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I forget Huybrechts's notation, but he certainly intends the product to be taken fiber-wise. I would have written $\otimes$, I guess. He wrote $\times$ because he is defining a product.

Comment: And what would be the pairing?

Comment: Precisely the one you have in mind. He's calling it a pairing because $\Lambda^r E \cong M\times \Bbb C$ is (non-canonically) the trivial bundle.